# PopupWindow.setWindowLayoutType() on API < 23

Tags: android, android-toast, android-popupwindow

I just want to know if there's a way of applying `PopupWindow.setWindowLayoutType()` on API < 23. Based on the documentation, it can only be use on API 23 and above. But is there a hack or workaround?

I have a custom `toast`. I want this `toast` to dismiss/cancel whenever the user tap/click it. But unfortunately, There's no way of interacting to the `toast`. I tried setting an `onClickListener` but got no luck. So I decided to use `PopupWindow` and adding a `handler` to dismiss the `PopupWindow` after 3sec. Everything is fine except that when navigating to the next screen, the `PopupWindow` also got dismissed. Then I applied `setWindowLayoutType` and set it to `setWindowLayoutType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_TOAST);`. It works but only on API 23 and above.

Any ideas on how can I apply this on lower API versions? Thanks.

ps. I don't want to use third party libraries.

Comment: When you say it "works but only on API 23 and above", do you mean you tried it on a lower API version and it didn't work, or do you mean you're just going by the documentation? 'cause I think the docs might be wrong about when that was added.

Comment: I tried it already but the popupWindow got dismiss when activity finished. unlike on api23 above, it still stays (like a toast).

Comment: Oh, OK, so you did try it, and it just didn't work as you were expecting. Yeah, the docs are wrong for that method. If it had just been added in API 23, then your app would've crashed when calling it In a lower API, but it was added a long time ago; in 2010, looking at the source.